# Why I can update rows during table lock in IX mode MySQL?

Tags: mysql

According to the [documentation of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html#innodb-intention-locks)

> Intention locks are table-level locks

So it means that intention locks hold the lock to the table but let's suppose I have a table drivers with the next fields

```
id |  name    | car_id
1  |  first   | 1
2  |  second  | 2
3  |  third   | 3
```

The first transaction is

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id, name, SLEEP(10) FROM drivers WHERE car_id > 5
FOR UPDATE;
COMMIT;
```

and the second

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE drivers SET name = 'new' WHERE id = 1;
COMMIT;
```

The second transaction has updated first record successfully and it is ok but the query

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```

shows that the table drivers was locked in IX mode

> TABLE LOCK table `drivers` trx id 3102 lock mode IX

So I can't understand the logic of table locking in InnoDB because as I understand the table lock must prevent other transactions with this table

Comment: If you lock the table then you can still do anything you like. Its locked so other people cannot get to it

Comment: Also, not sure why you would commit a select?

Comment: Question? Are there any `car_id` that are greater than 5?

Comment: So that is the question. Why innodb says that the table is locked but i still can update some records

Comment: Sorry did you read the first comment? If its you that locked the table or row You are still allowed to update it

Comment: If you want to test the locking mechanism, you have to login using another session (another account is simplest) and while the lock is still in place attempt to make an update that will effect the locked table/row

Comment: I did it. The transactions from the head of the topic were executed from two different sessions